# Inserting a Confirm/Cancel pop-up into JQuery - CSS Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am still quite new to JQuery and I am trying to make a simple pop-up message to confirm a delete, but I want the table row to turn red during this process.

I found this code that seems sweet, short, and simple.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.confirm').click(function(){
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
        if (answer){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

from: http://brettgregson.com/programming/how-to-make-a-are-you-sure-pop-up-with-jquery/138

And I am "attempting" to add it onto my current deleteFunction(), but I am still pretty new to JQuery and I am having some "bugs" with it.

My deleteFunction (no confirmation - but color updating works fine)

```
function deleteFunction(element) {
        var newID = $(element).closest("td").find("span.ID").text();
        $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'red');
        $.post(
                '@Url.Action("customDelete", "Movie")',
                 {
                     'id': newID
                 },
                function (data) { },
                "json"
            );
        $(element).closest("tr").hide();
    }
```

My insertion of the confirmation box works, but does not update the tr background color, nor does it revert the color back to the default upon cancellation.

```
function deleteFunction(element) {
    var newID = $(element).closest("td").find("span.ID").text();
    $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'red');

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
        if (answer) {
            $.post(
        '@Url.Action("customDelete", "Movie")',
        {
            'id': newID
        },
        function (data) { },
        "json"
        );
            $(element).closest("tr").remove();
            return true;
        } else {
            $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'default');
            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

If someone could explain why the CSS color is not being touched until after the confirmation box appears (or why it does not remove the color after Cancel is pressed) it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you did not change your html markup, i.e. there is no element with "confirm" class name, would you confirm this?

Comment: Yup, I JUST realized this. *facepalm* I got it working now. I do have one side-question then, how do I get the red-background to display before the pop-up appears, it doesn't show up at all now unless I hit cancel.

Comment: code/question edited. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle for you: **[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7j97t/2/)**. As for clearing the color, you should use `css('background-color', 'initial')`. As for highlighting - it should highlight, as sample does. If it does not help, then feel free to reveal your html markup, most likely the issue is there

Comment: The red did not appear, but the initial color remains upon hitting cancel, so that's closer! :) You want me to post my View?

Comment: Hold on, first - which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. Also, I tried my code again with the "initial" color for cancel and everything works great like yours except the red still does not appear during the dialogue. Is there some weird order of operation thing with JQUery?

Comment: It seems like the color affect does not occur till after the function has fully executed..or something like that

Comment: Ok, if you are able to run given sample and it does work fine, but yours code is not working, then I am pretty sure the issue is in markup, i.e. go ahead and share the markup

Comment: Right now both of our code(s) work for cancel, but neither show the red during the dialogue.

Comment: I found the culprit. `<table class="table-hover">` since I ended my mouseover on a button, it left the hover-effect in place which overrules the background color.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your delete function if user wants to delete, like this way
here is your delete function:

```
function deleteFunction(element) {
    var newID = $(element).closest("td").find("span.ID").text();
    $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'red');
    $.post(
            '@Url.Action("customDelete", "Movie")',
             {
                 'id': newID
             },
            function (data) { },
            "json"
        );
    $(element).closest("tr").hide();
}
```

and here is cofirm to delete:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ans=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");
 if(ans)
    {
     deleteFunction(element);
     }
   else
    {
        return false;
     }
});
```

Comment: I shall try this out! 1 moment

Comment: This gave me a few bugs, but I was able to modify the idea bit. I have also slightly updated the code/question edited. Thank you!